# Django not authenticated redirect

Tags: django, django-templates

What would be the best implementation to redirect a user who is not signed in? Is there a better way then to use a `@is_autenticated` type decerator in every single view?

The alternative I have thought of is to have a `base.html` which checks for `is_authenticated` and every html will extend base. Ex:

base.html

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  {% block content %}
    content here
  {% endblock content %}

{% else %}
   redirect
```

I feel though this way puts view logic into the template which really doesn't sit well but it would avoid a decorator on every function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some middleware. Personally, I think having the redirect in the template (I'm assuming in javascript code) is very ugly. Django-stronghold (https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold) is nice if most views require authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Django has an in-built authentication model.Authentication logic should always be in the views and including view logic in the template is a bad practice.Once the user is authenticated, you can render a homepage from the views along with a welcome message.You can do the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
# login to home page - 
def home(request):


    try:
        username = password = ''
        if request.POST:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            print username
            print password
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            print "User value is",user

         if user is not None:
           if user.is_active:
               login(request, user)
               request.session['username'] = username
               return render_to_response('home.html',{"message": "Welcome"})
           # Redirect to a success page.
           else:
               return render_to_response('login.html',{"message": "User is Inactive"})

            # Return a 'disabled account' error message

         else:
           return render_to_response('login.html',{"message": "Invalid Credential"})
        else:
            return render_to_response('home.html',{"user" : request.session['username']})
    except:
        return render_to_response('error.html',{"message": sys.exc_info()[0]})
```